# Blank display of a partition

Tags: partitioning, mount

I am facing a peculiar problem for the first time. One of the partition in the hard drive shows empty, but it has all the contents. Please see the attached file.

When I searched folders on the same partition it displays all the contents of that particular folder. But it is not displaying the first content page.

I tried through terminal but it shows following error;

$ ls /mnt/data/

ls: reading directory '/mnt/data/': Input/output error

Please help to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance
RB

[hidden contents in a partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vW5WG.png)

[search report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jam3d.png)

Comment: Have you tried simply rebooting Ubuntu?

Comment: An input/output error usually indicates a hardware fault. I wouldn't say this is 100% certain, but I suggest you start by [looking at SMART data](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1) on the disk. You could also try replacing cables.

Comment: Dear Android Dev & Smith

Reboot doesn't work. I did Smart test both short and extended, but no changes. When I do search through Dash I can see some files and folder, but not all. I can copy thos files also. But I could not search certain important data. What should I do to retrieve my data? 
Thanks
Ramesh